# Update ViewHolder values of custom Adapter for Recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, custom-adapter, android-viewholder

I have a `RecyclerView` with a custom `Adapter` to display rectangular elements (about 15, the number can change if the user adds/removes items) in a grid (using `Gridlayout Manager`).
[image: RecyclerView]

These elements consist of an `ImageView` and a `TextView`. I want to update both Views regularly after receiving new results from network requests (say every 2minutes).

What would be the best way to update these views? How can I identify the specific `ViewHolder`? How can I access the `ViewHolder` values of these elements? Would it be best to keep a reference to each `ViewHolder` in the `Activity` where I want to change them? Or should I create a new element with the new values and replace the current element with it? What would be considered best practice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are storing your value of image view and text view in an arraylist you can call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter when you have a change in the dataset.

For example if you have say a Grid object whose attributes include image uri(to set the image) and string(to set in text view) and some Array list say

```
List<Grid> gridList = new ArrayList<>();
```

you can update whatever new data you get in the Arraylist and after you are done updating in the array list call

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply, I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is update views and it's data when some data change. You have to do this always.  The method

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged
```

do this for you.
When you update some data you have to tell to the system,  because there's an important action named recycle,  when you use a view holder you giving the possibility to the system recycle a view,  what means views that don't change the date are stored on the view holder,  so the list doesn't need to use the

```
findViewById
```

again.